# How To Deploy Project On Heroku

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, salesforce, heroku-api

I have **one project that project in nodejs and Angular divided** into **Two Parts One is Backend And One is Frontend.**
**Backend** Cosist Api And my Sql Connection.There used Nodejs
**Frontend** Consist Ui coding.There used Angular

> **This Project Are Required to run Differently means First Run Backend in 1st CMD And then Run Frontend in 2nd CMD.**

> ****Means Backend not run then Frontend give Error****

***""Then This All frontend and Backend Project How to deploy into Heroku and run into salesforce?""***

Comment: You make two projects in heroku and change the paths from localhost to the real paths.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create 2 git repo (either on gitlab or github), then set a CI/CD who will build and deploy your project, the process will also start everything on your server. There is a whole documentation on Heroku you can find [here for NodeJS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) and [here for Angular](https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) you have all the information you need to configure heroku cli

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBfcbb07Tqk&ab_channel=TraversyMedia) you'll find some info on deploying fontend and backend to heruku.